# The caller does not have permission to request "people/me". Request requires one of the following scopes: [profile]

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I Receive this error

{
error: {
code: 403,
message: 'The caller does not have permission to request "people/me". Request requires one of the following scopes: [profile].',
status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED'
}
}

After I got the authorization code through the following URL, I got an access_token and used it as follows.

export const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI}&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

```
  try {
    RepUser = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
  }
```

There seems to be an authentication problem, is there something wrong with the scope to get the authorization code??

what's the problem??

Comment: I think the problem is not in the auth rather than the scopes you passed, you need to check the necessary scope for that action , in my knowledge after working with google apis if you have a problem with the token it return 401 unauthorized, can you please share the scopes that you asked for ?

Answer (score 3):

As per your error:

{ error: { code: 403, message: 'The caller does not have permission to request "people/me". **Request requires one of the following scopes: [profile].'**, status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED' } }

Add this other scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Comment: I added this permission + all permissions required for get method :
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#authorization-scopes
Still get the same error.

Comment: @emiliezawadzki did you remember to reset your token.json file with the new scopes before running again?